# DIV height not changing according to css

Tags: css, html

So, I have a div placed inside a form. The form is stretched at min-height 100% but the child div refuses to stretch after putting the height or min-height to 100%. But the div stretches when the form height not min-height is set 100%. Why does this happen?

```
<form>
<div id="host">
</div>
</form>

body, html{
    height: 100%;
}
form
{
    min-height: 100%;
}

#host{
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fkuE8/

Answer (score 2):

min-height: is used to set the minimum height of a element for example

```
  height: 100%;         /* full height  */
  min-height: 100px;   /* at least  100px */
```

if you set a percentage it will use the least amount of space possible

Answer (score 0):

You also need **form** height as 100%

```
body, html, form {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Demo here - [jsfiddle.net/DCf23/](http://jsfiddle.net/DCf23/)